# Boolean selection and masked assignment

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Newbie pandas question regarding boolean selection in `DataFrame`. Say I have the following in which I would like to take all entries that are `> 1` and set them to 3

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(10, 4), index=np.arange(10),
              columns=["a", "b", "c", "d"])

s[np.abs(s) > 1] = np.sign(s) * 3
```

The RHS is of different shape than LHS, how come this works fine and I don't have to do

```
s[np.abs(s) > 1] = np.sign(s[np.abs(s) > 1]) * 3
```

My understanding is that the LHS of both of these expressions returns a view on to the elements where the expression in brackets evaluates to `True`. However, examining the LHS of the first statement shows that it returns `NaN` for elements where the selection statement is `False`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are missing is that an indexing statement in Python can have different meanings based on whether it is on the RHS or LHS of an assignment.  In your case:

```
s[np.abs(s) > 1] = np.sign(s) * 3
```

This results in a call to `pd.DataFrame.__setitem__(s, np.abs(s) > 1, np.sign(s) * 3).  And since`np.abs(s) > 1`returns True only in certain cells, Pandas implements`**setitem**()` to only modify those cells.  This is just a useful convention--nothing in the Python language enforces it per se.

On the other hand if you say:

```
print(s[np.abs(s) > 1])
```

This results in a call to `pd.DataFrame.__getitem__(s, np.abs(s) > 1)`.  And Pandas implements this by returning a DataFrame with the same shape as `s` but with the "missing" values filled with `NAN`.

So when you do the assignment, don't imagine that Pandas is creating a DataFrame with NAN values where the condition is False, then assigning to that DataFrame.  That's not what happens.  It just copies the values from the RHS to the LHS wherever the condition is True.

Comment: I would just add one thing--`s.values[np.abs(s) > 1]` does return a 1d array as described by [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) docs.  Which can be confusing because as you mentioned, calling just `s[np.abs(s) > 1]` is different than assigning to it.